# Prove that f(x,y) is surjective over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions

How to prove that $$f :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$$ s.t.
$$f(x,y)=2x^3-3x^2+2y^3+3y^2$$is surjection?

I have to find $(x,y)$ such that $$2x^3-3x^2+2y^3+3y^2=a$$

Comment: Try plotting $x \mapsto f(x,0)$.

Comment: This has a solution $(x,0)$ by the intermediate value theorem, (and also $(0,y)$).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Prove that $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, defined as $g(x)=f(x,0)$ is a surjection.

Comment: $2x^3-3x^2=a$ thus $x^2(2x-3)=a$ How to calculate $x$?

Comment: @george_smile You don't need to. Just look at the limits of $f$ as $x\to \infty$ and $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$a = f(( \sqrt[3]{\frac 1 4a}, \sqrt[3]{\frac 1 4a}))$.

Comment: isn't it just.  But it's clear.  If x = y the the square terms vanish and the cube terms double. and 2x^3 <=> x is clearly one to one.

Answer (score 0):

For any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ let $b=2y^3+3y^2$.  The function becomes:

$$
f(x,b)=2x^3-3x^2+b
$$
that is a family of cubics each of wich has range (image) $(-\infty,+\infty)$.